# How to avoid mkdir path redirected to SysWOW64

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I'm tring to create some directories (dirs) using a .bat file. At the cmd.exe, I can create the dirs normally, but when runing the commands inside a .bat file, for some odd reason, the dirs are created inside the SysWOW64 directory.

Win 7 x64 SP1 PRO

How can I tell Windows to create the dirs at the correct path?

Commands:

```
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds
```

Inside bat, results in: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\System32\oobe\info

---

Using a shortcut to cmd.exe and running it as administrator the dirs are still created inside SysWOW64.
ex:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "D:\Test.bat"
 or
%windir%\System32\runas.exe /user:Administrator %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "D:\Test.bat"
```

but if a open the cmd.exe manually as administrator and run the .bat file, it works! What a heck??

---

edit 2

I found out why. It is because I was running the .bat inside XYPlorer and not Windows Explorer (WE). Inside WE the .bat works. `But a shortcut opened inside a 32 bit explorer is not able to run a 62 bit cmd.exe ?`

Comment: Open a run window, type in `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` and run your script from there. Does the script work as it should then? What if you run `c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe` and then run the script?

Comment: How can I make a bat do that?

Comment: Use this command: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "name of your script"` If this works, I can write an answer that will (hopefully) make your script launch the 64-bit command interpreter itself. Unfortunately, I don't have a 64-bit version of Windows on my computer to test this.

Comment: Just tried it on my system and I don't get the same behaviour... c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "name of your script" is what my bat has for command line, so that should be it.

Comment: run the 64Bit CMD.exe, not the 32Bit one.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: It must be a XYPlorer limitation in that it runs under WOW in 32-bit. Is your XYPlorer 64 bit?

Comment: There is only the 32 bit version. I need to run the bat inside the normal windows explorer. But it is odd that I can't load a 64 cmd inside a 32 explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **absolutely confident** that writing folders in `C:\Windows\system32\` is a good idea (probably not, but YMMV), and you don't want the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) to automatically redirect your file, and you must write with a 32-bit process, then use the path `C:\Windows\sysnative\` and it will write out to the `system32` folder.

Caution: it's probably not a great idea to go messing with these folders unless you fully understand what you are doing. Read the File System Redirector link a couple of times.

Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100443), as it's really great.

Comment: I fully understand what I'm doing. Changing windows default start/lock background. I did that a lot of times and need some automatization. Now I'm using Windows 10 and I like its background, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The SysWOW64 is a feature in windows system folder structures and in windows registry.  But this feature causes major problems for automation.  Here's some info about the SysWOW emulator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249(VS.85).aspx

To work around this issue you need to either launch a 64bit version on command prompt or use MS's folder redirection.